# Trouble with the silent installation command wamp 3.2.x and mysql v5.7.x

Tags: command-line, mysql

I used to silently install wamp with the following command:

```
start /w wampserver3.1.9_x64.exe /VERYSILENT /SUPPRESSMSGBOXES /NORESTART /NOCANCEL /DIR="%HOMEDRIVE%\wamp64" /LANG="en"
```

Now with wamp v3.2.0 MySQL is not installed by default:

[image]

So this command does not install MySQL:

```
start /w wampserver3.2.0_x64.exe /VERYSILENT /SUPPRESSMSGBOXES /NORESTART /NOCANCEL /DIR="%HOMEDRIVE%\wamp64" /LANG="en"
```

Now wamp has 2 MySQL. v8x and v5.7x. These are the [InnoSetup options](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setupcmdline) (wampserver3.2.0_x64.exe /HELP):

[image]

I have tried the following switches and the result is this:

Not install MySQL:

```
/COMPONENTS=mysql5.7.28
/COMPONENTS=mysqlv5.7.28
/COMPONENTS="mysqlv5*"
/COMPONENTS="mysql5*"
/COMPONENTS="mysql 5*"
/COMPONENTS="mysql v5*"
/COMPONENTS="mysqlv5.7.28"
```

Install MySql v8.0.18 instead of v5.7.28:

```
/COMPONENTS="mysql v5.7.28"
/COMPONENTS="mysql 5.7.28"
/COMPONENTS="mysql"
```

**How do I add MySQL v5.7.x installation to my command? (switch to select mysql)**

Thk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just type.

for MySQL 5.7.X : `/COMPONENTS="MYSQL/MYSQL57"`

for MySQL 8.0.X : `/COMPONENTS="MYSQL/MYSQL80"`

See here in iis file.
[source file wampserver inno setup.](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/files/WampServer%203/WampServer%203.0.0/Install%20iss/)

```
[Components]
Name: "main"; Description: "Wampmanager"; Types: full custom; Flags: fixed
Name: "APACHE"; Description: "Apache {#WAMPAPACHEVERSION}"; Types: full custom; Flags: fixed
Name: "PHP56"; Description: "PHP {#WAMPPHPVERSION56}"; Types: full custom; Flags: Fixed
Name: "PHP70"; Description: "PHP {#WAMPPHPVERSION70}"; Types: custom
Name: "PHP71"; Description: "PHP {#WAMPPHPVERSION71}"; Types: custom
Name: "PHP72"; Description: "PHP {#WAMPPHPVERSION72}"; Types: custom
Name: "PHP73"; Description: "PHP {#WAMPPHPVERSION73}"; Types: full custom; Flags: Fixed
Name: "PHP74"; Description: "PHP {#WAMPPHPVERSION74}"; Types: full custom; Flags: Fixed
Name: "MARIADB"; Description: "MariaDB"; Types: full custom; Flags: Fixed
Name: "MARIADB/MARIADB104"; Description: "MariaDB {#WAMPMARIADBVERSION104}"; Flags: Exclusive
Name: "MARIADB/MARIADB103"; Description: "MariaDB {#WAMPMARIADBVERSION103}"; Flags: Exclusive
Name: "MYSQL"; Description: "MySQL"; Types: custom
#ifdef WAMP64BIT
Name: "MYSQL/MYSQL80"; Description: "MySQL {#WAMPMYSQLVERSION80}"; Types: custom; Flags: Exclusive
#endif
Name: "MYSQL/MYSQL57"; Description: "MySQL {#WAMPMYSQLVERSION57}"; Types: custom; Flags: Exclusive
Name: "APPS"; Description: "Applications"; Types: full custom; Flags: Fixed
Name: "APPS/PHPMYADMIN"; Description: "PhpMyAdmin {#WAMPPHPMYADMINVERSION}"; Types: full custom; Flags: Fixed
Name: "APPS/ADMINER"; Description: "Adminer {#WAMPADMINERVERSION}"; Types: full custom; Flags: Fixed
Name: "APPS/PHPSYSINFO"; Description: "PhpSysInfo {#WAMPPHPSYSINFOVERSION}"; Types: full custom; Flags: Fixed
```

Example:

```
start /wait wampserver3.2.0_x64.exe /DIR="C:\wamp" /VERYSILENT /SUPPRESSMSGBOXES /COMPONENTS="MYSQL/MYSQL57"
```